# Cypress, If statement not working no matter what i try

Tags: typescript, if-statement, conditional-statements, cypress

I'm trying to do a simple test in Cypress to see if a field is read only but no matter what i try i cant get the if statement to work, ive checked the cypress documentation and been through a load of different types of examples, i normally dont have an issue grabbing hold of elements and working with them but i'm a bit stumped with this, what am i missing?:

(Ive tried this with .hasClass and .find but still no luck, ive also tried using the other attributes of the element but nothing works)

Heres the html code for the field i want to interact with:

```html
<textarea _ngcontent-nud-c545="" rows="1" cdktextareaautosize="" 
  aria-label="Product name" matinput="" type="text" 
  placeholder="'Enter a product name...'" required="" 
  formcontrolname="productName" 
  class="cdk-textarea-autosize mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c98-55 ng-pristine ng-valid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-touched" 
  ng-reflect-enabled="" ng-reflect-type="text" ng-reflect-placeholder="'Enter a product name...'" ng-reflect-required="" ng-reflect-name="productName" id="mat-input-3" data-placeholder="'Enter a product name...'" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" style="height: 21px;">              </textarea>
```

Heres my code to grab it and test to see if it includes text 'productName':

```
cy.get('[formcontrolname="productName"]').then (($productName) => {

  if ($productName.text().includes('productName')) {
    cy.log('its found it');

  } else {
    cy.log('it hasnt found it');
  }

});
```

No matter what i try the if statement goes to 'it hasnt found it'

[image: Screenshot of the dom]

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the dom after you have entered the product name ?

Comment: The values thats in the product name field is 'Clay brick unit....', i was trying to grab hold of the element by referencing some text within that element, ie 'productName' or 'Product name', ive uploaded a screenshot of the dom anyway

Comment: Maybe I missed something but you typed `clay brick unit...` in the textarea. Why  do you expect to see that it has `productName` ?

Comment: I was expecting the code to still find that 'productName' text as it exists within the element........i am fairly new to Cypress so i might be a little off with my understanding....but i thought the .text() would just search for text within an element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that worked for me is shown below, previously my If statement just wouldnt work, i couldnt seem to select the text field i wanted when using an alias of the page element, using the .val() function resolved this issue. With the .val() i could grab the value of the text field and then compare that with an expected value, in our case the expected value was 'Clay brick unit'

Code explanation:
I use 'cy.get('[formcontrolname="productName"]')' to grab the text field i need, i then create an alias called '$productName', i then use the .val() function to return the value from the text field ($productName), i then use the if statement to see if the value within my text field includes 'Clay brick unit', if it does output 'its found it', if it doesnt find it output 'It hasnt found it' to the log

```
cy.get('[formcontrolname="productName"]').then(($productName) => {
      const val = $productName.val() as string;   // specify the returned value type
      if (val.includes('Clay brick unit')) {
        cy.log('its found it');

      } else {
        cy.log('it hasnt found it');
      }

    });

    return this;

  }
```

Comment: Please add a bit more context to your answer.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `text()` you have to use `.val()`

```js
cy.get('[formcontrolname="productName"]').then(($productName) => {
  if ($productName.val().includes('Clay brick unit')) {
    cy.log('its found it');
  } else {
    cy.log('it hasnt found it');
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks but the code in your post now give me some errors: Object is possibly 'undefined'. & Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string | number | string[]'.
  Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'number'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to confirm the element, if so you will need `.attr()` not `.text()`

```js
cy.get('[formcontrolname="productName"]').then (($productName) => {

  if ($productName.attr('formcontrolname').includes('productName')) {
    cy.log('its found it');

  } else {
    cy.log('it hasnt found it');
  }

});
```

But actually, if it's **not found** the `.then()` part will not run - the test will fail on `cy.get('[formcontrolname="productName"]')` because the `.get()` command has a built-in existence assertion.

The problems you are getting with `$productName.val()` is typescript complaining that it can't resolve which type is returned.

Try

```
const val = $productName.val() as string;   // specify the returned value type
if (val.includes('Clay brick unit')) {
```

Comment: thanks but I tried your code and it errors on the .attr() - Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)

Comment: Initially I posted the wrong syntax, but add the `'formcontrolname'` parameter and it should be good.

Comment: You can also experiment with the built-in assertion in `.get()`. Change it to `cy.get('[formcontrolname="NOT-CORRECT"]')` and the test will fail.

Comment: I tried using the amended syntax and this line ($productName.attr('formcontrolname')) now errors with - Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

Comment: I'm assuming the "cy.get('[formcontrolname="productName"]').then (($productName) => {" part is working because when i debug it the $productName variable contains the correct value, ie [formcontrolname="productName"] which also correctly identifies/highlights the product name field when used in playground selector, ie cy.get('[formcontrolname="productName"]')